# How can cmake fully set the shared library installation path?

Tags: cmake

cmake always installs shared libraries to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PATH}/lib`, is there any way for cmake to not create a `lib` directory and install shared libraries directly to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PATH}`?

I want to use the shared library as a lua module for neovim, which has an absolute path requirement for the directory where the shared library is stored.

I don't want to set `LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH`, I set it to the `test` directory for testing the shared library.

Here is some environmental information.

OS: Archlinux

cmake version: 3.25.2

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, the `install()` function has a `DESTINATION` that sets the installation path of the shared path directly, the example is as follows:

```
install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} DESTINATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lua")
```

For more information on the `install()` function, please see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html

Comment: You shouldn't be using absolute paths as `DESTINATION`. Otherwise you'll end up with problems when using `cmake --install ... --prefix ...` or `cpack`.

Comment: @fabian Please read the question clearly. On Unix-like systems, we usually install shared libraries into the /lib or /usr/lib directory, which just needs to be set to `-prefix`. But this problem is not about installing a shared library as a rule, it is about generating a shared library that is then dynamically loaded by the interpreter of the lua script. It has to be in a specific directory in order to be found by lua. If you just set `-prefix`, cmake will install the dynamic library in the `-prefix/lib` directory, which will prevent lua from finding the dynamic library.

Comment: @fabian As pointed out in the question, setting `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PATH}` in CMakeLists.txt is not the ideal solution; you set `--prefix` in cmake's command line arguments, which may seem like a different approach but actually has the same effect.